# Could someone help describe the two types of array storage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, v8

I'm reading this article about V8 on [HTML5Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/).  The article is old but I understand almost none of it and it bothers me.  I'm taking this 1 step at a time but could someone help me with the Arrays section?

The article states:

> **Arrays**
>
> In order to handle large and sparse arrays, there are two types of
> array storage internally:
>
> - **Fast Elements:** linear storage for compact key sets
> - **Dictionary Elements:** hash table storage otherwise
>
> It's best not to cause the array storage to flip from one type to
> another.

**Question:**

What would a **Fast Elements** linear storage array look like?

What would a **Dictionary Elements** hash table array look like?

For prevention purposes, how would I *"flip from one type to another"*?

Comment: i think linear storage array would be normal array with just single elements and hash storage would be array of objects.

Comment: The article does not speak of *elements*, but *dictionary elements*. You did not reflect the quote that well.

Comment: @trincot sorry copy and mistake.

Comment: Ok, but now you have a trailing word Dictionary in the first option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will go a little other way round.

2) What would `Dictionary Elements` hash table Array look like?

A JavaScript object is a map from string to values. e.g.

```
var obj = {
  "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
  "address": "221B Baker Street"
}
```

V8 uses hash tables to represent objects unless using an optimized representation for *special cases*. This is much like a dictionary uses (words, meaning) pair.

Now, this hash table access is slow because initially all the keys and values in a hash table are `undefined`. On inserting a new pair, a hash is computed and the pair inserted at the insertion index. If there's already a key at that index, attempt to insert at next one and so on.

1) What would `Fast Elements` Linear storage Array look like?

In V8, an `element` is a **property whose key is a non-negative integer (0, 1, 2, ...)** i.e. a simple linear array whose properties can be accessed via a numerical index.

Fast elements are stored in a contiguous array. e.g.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

They are a *special case* that is optimised for faster access as the index is already known and not to be computed.

3) For prevention purposes, How would I `flip from one type to another`?

For fast element, if you assign an index that's way past the end of the elements array, V8 may downgrade the elements to dictionary mode.

Reference: http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Don’t delete array elements. It would make the array transition to a slower internal representation. When the key set becomes sparse, V8 will eventually switch elements to dictionary mode, which is even slower. https://jsperf.com/packed-vs-holey-arrays

Comment: @User528491, _They are a special case that is optimised for faster_ - but still a hash table, correct?

Answer (score 4):

**sir i can be wrong but according to your question what i have observed is explained**

*when we initialise an array it internally gets key as 0,1,2....etc as i pushed element with value its into array but array does not consider it*

```
ex :

var arr = new Array()

arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = "myname";
arr['myname'] = nick;
```

but when i do arr.length i get 3 so it does not consider the key apart from numeric but if i write `arr[3] = {myname:'nick'}` then it consider it as elements.

internally i think to keep the linear array different it looks for '{}'

Comment: So liner is a[0] a[1] ... a[20] where hashtable would be a['myname'] = 'nick' ?

Comment: no a['myname'] = nick would be considered if its an object not an array elements